# Why do I have to manually specify the QAction::MenuRole in Qt 5.1?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5

In Qt 4.8 I had this code:

```
    QMenuBar *menu_bar = menuBar(); //of my QMainWindow
    QMenu *help_menu = menu_bar->addMenu(tr("&Help"));
    QAction *about_qt_action = help_menu->addAction(tr("About &Qt"));
    connect(about_qt_action, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(aboutQt()));
```

This alone was sufficient for Qt to automatically move the About Qt menu item to the application menu under OS X 10.8 (and maybe other versions too).

Now with Qt 5.1 my About Qt item ends up in the Help menu, and I have to manually set the MenuRole to get back the old behavior:

```
    about_qt_action->setMenuRole(QAction::AboutQtRole);
```

However, [the documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtwidgets/qaction.html#menuRole-prop) says:

> By default all action have the TextHeuristicRole, which means that the action is added based on its text (see QMenuBar for more information).

And:

> Qt for Mac OS X also provides a menu bar merging feature to make QMenuBar conform more closely to accepted Mac OS X menu bar layout. The merging functionality is based on string matching the title of a QMenu entry. These strings are translated (using QObject::tr()) in the "QMenuBar" context. If an entry is moved its slots will still fire as if it was in the original place. The table below outlines the strings looked for and where the entry is placed if matched:

... and [the table](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtwidgets/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x) shows `about.*` for menus that are moved to the application menu. My application is named Yua, and an "About Yua" QAction made in the same way also is not moved unless I manually set the MenuRole. There is both a `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName` entry in my Info.plist. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably a bug in Qt. Can you please check if it's already in the [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/), and if not, write a minimal testcase and open one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply not ever rely on heuristic roles. They are IMHO a rather ill-conceived feature. You are supposed to manually set the menu roles on all menu actions that have non-default roles. That's all there is to it.